# how to access html element color in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

My html file makes a tag: Good car with like and dislike button. So that user can select like or unlike. Also there is submit button on screen to submit response. Code in html file is as below :
 Good Car  
Save Feedback

Also I do have PHP file. What I want is that when user clicks submit then my php file/code records the color of my like or dislike button (i applied these in java script code part ) and save in DB.

I don't know how to access the color of like or dislike button from html in PHP. So that if like is green then it means it has been clicked and I could increment the value in DB and similar for for dislike.

Comment: 1) you should post your code so we can see what have you tried. 2) why the uppercase? seems like you are yelling

Comment: <span class="tags">
Good Car
<i id="b1" class="thumbsup fa fa-thumbs-up" ></i> 
<i name="dislike1_color" class="thumbsdown fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>
</span><button type="submit" name="addfeed" class="w3-btn w3-green">Save Feedback</button>

Comment: `php` is a server-side language and cannot get elements color but you can use `javascript` to get the color and send that to `php`

Comment: You could also use the PHP `echo` to add the elements.

Comment: @JackStoller not sure what help using `echo` to add elements will be to getting the color....

Comment: For instance , in javascript if i have : <script>
var i=0; </script>. how i can access this in php ?

Comment: @NewToJS when you reload the page it would be. Then you can just use JS to change the color when you click it so you don't have to reload it.

Comment: @user3196663 You can't. server-side source code will execute on the server before executing client-side languages in the browser like `javascript` You can send variables to `php` though.

Comment: @user3196663 Use a [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_httprequest.asp) to send data from JS to PHP

Comment: @NewToJS how i can send variables to php ? Kindly guide

Comment: my html form has some text fields and some like/dislike icons. like /dislike buttons change color on selection. so what i want is that when user submits form then in php i check the color of like/dislike and save imcrement/decrement value accordingly in DB. i am totally confused how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i can see how you could do this with php is if you submit the color in a form. 
PHP is a server-side language as a comment allready explained. Meaning that it cant directly access everything that happens on a client side to make it simple.

An idea how you could solve your problem tho is:

- If a user clicks on a from a get request is submited and it appends an attribute to the url (example.com?color=green)

  ```
  <form action="/action_page.php" target="_blank" method="GET">
     //This is your button
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    //this is the color
    <input type="hidden" name="color" value="green">
  </form>
  ```
- in php you can now check if the color get param is set and if it is you can get its value

  ```
  <?php
     var color = "";
     if (isset($_GET['color'])) {
       color = htmlspecialchars($_GET['color']);

       //To check the color use always 3 = to evade type juggling
       if(color === "green")
          //do something
       elseif(color === "red")
          //do something else

     }
  ?>
  ```

  //make sure not to blindly handle user input tho.

Comment: 1-my form has other elements as well and currently it's having method=Post. Not sure what should i do in this situation ?                                         2-my element is <i id="b1" class="thumbsup fa fa-thumbs-up" ></i>. now i have to access color for element with id:b1. again not sure how i can do this in php